# Connect to Deprecated Sybase Database

Tags: c#, java, sybase, sybase-asa

I'm trying to connect to a Sybase Adaptive SQL Anywhere database that is running version 9. I'm currently trying to use `iAnywhere.Data.AsaClient.dll`. When I try to create a new connection,

```
 AsaConnection myConnection = new AsaConnection();
```

I get  `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` stating `File dbdata9.dll was not found`.

I can't find `dbdata9.dll` anywhere and it seems as if Sybase has long since deprecated that version. Is there anyway to get this file or are there any other tools that I can use to get access to this data programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Java instead, following [this article](http://dcx.sybase.com/1101/en/dbprogramming_en11/connecting-establishing-jdbc.html) with a few modifications. I have access to jconn4.jar so I was able to add that as a reference.